# In sql 2008 R2, how do i join 2 columns from one table with 2 columns in another table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, inner-join, multiple-columns

I have 2 tables. In table1 I have 2 columns -- cust_npa & cust_nxx. In table2, I have 2 columns -- valid_npa & valid_nxx. Each entry in table2.valid_npa has a corresponding entry in table2.valid_nxx.

```
valid_npa   valid_nxx
201         551
201         552
201         553
202         851
202         852
```

I wish to return all the rows in table1 that have a combination of valid_nap & valid_nxx from table2.

For example, a row in table1 that has cust_npa of 201 and cust_nxx of 852 would not be returned (as this is not a valid combination from table2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table_A as A
inner join table_B as B
on A.id = B.id and A.name = B.name
```

Comment: does it matter that table1 and table2 are in different databases?

Comment: if they are in different databases, you can make synonyms and use them, if different tables not at all.

Comment: Thanks, this helps immensely. I'm new to the whole SQL game, and this seems simple enough -- of course hindsight being what it is.

Comment: If I was looking for the opposite, i.e., return all the rows in table1 that do not have a combination of valid_npa & valid_nxx from table2, would i just use the <> operator?

Answer (score 0):

```
select valid_npa, valid_nxx from table2
intersect
select cust_npa, cust_nxx from table1
```

Comment: Would there be any reason why this query produces significantly different results than the one provided above?

Comment: Intersect will return distinct results, whereas an inner join without a distinct would return multiple identical rows.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. In my case, I would like to see multiple identical rows. Thank you for clarifying this for me!